# Is it is possible to Auto addition and subtraction in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone please help me if there is any possibility for adding and subtracting in excel.

Eg: Suppose i have 10 rows A and B

1. It should Add A1 and Subtract B1 and result will be displayed in C1, it works but Problem is like

It should Add A= A1,A2,A3......A100  and  Add with B= B1,B2,B3....B100 and Subtract A- B result should be displayed at C100. Another Scenario Add A= A1,A2...A53 , Add B= B1, B2....B53 and Substarct A- B result should be displayed at C53

I need a function like it should add all rows A and B of  and Subtract A-B it and Result should be displayed at the same Cell or row in C. It should perform for N no. of rows

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want a sum with dynamic range? Can you prepare some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

To get the row-by-row differences, in **C1** enter:

```
=A1-B1
```

and copy downward:

[image]

To get the accumulated differences, enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:A1-$B$1:B1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]